# Send Grid send email failed on localhost in laravel 5.7.29

Tags: laravel, email, sendgrid

Im trying to send email from my local host using sendgrid, packages s-ichikawa 2.1.0 , laravel 5.7.29, Im getting this Error

> Client error: `POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: {"errors":[{"message":"The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error (truncated...) *

Same code working on other project in API , but on localhost Im this error.

MY Controller Code:

```
$email = 'umermajeed93@hotmail.com';
$name  = 'Umer Majeed';
Mail::to($email)->send(new SendMailable($name ,$email))
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Sichikawa\LaravelSendgridDriver\SendGrid;

class SendMailable extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    use SendGrid;
    public $name;
    public $code;
    public $email;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($name,$email)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {        
        $address = 'noreply@retailplatform.com';
        $subject = 'New Ad';

         return $this
            ->view('Admin.email')
            ->subject($subject)
            ->from($address)
            ->to([$this->email])
            ->sendgrid([
                'personalizations' => [
                    [
                        'substitutions' => [
                            ':myname' => 's-ichikawa',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ])->with('name',$this->name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the test environment only emails are sent to your test account, which you set up in the .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
```

in production you could already send emails to the recipient of your choice, but on the local server you cannot